# Ничем НЕмотивированные. НЕ слитно или - раздельно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

> В данном случае у больного, страдающего в течение ряда лет
> периодически обостряющейся шизофренией, имеют место непонятные для
> него, **ничем немотивированные** состояния страха и тревоги,
> возникающие всегда при соприкосновении с окружающими людьми и
> сопровождающиеся неясными опасениями какой-то опасности со стороны
> этих людей.

Так написано в книге 1957 года "Шизофрения: клиника и механизмы шизофренического бреда", автор - Елена Николаевна Каменева.

Слитное написание "НЕ" - ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По современным правилам должно писаться **ничем не мотивированный**.

Надо учесть, что современные правила (в том числе и то, которое регламентирует написание в данном случае "не" раздельно с прилагательным) были приняты в 1956 г. Так что возможно, что книга 1957 г. издания просто не была ещё редактирована в соответствии с обязательными унифицированными правилами, ведь книги готовятся к изданию раньше, чем издаются.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, элементарная опечатка. Отрицательная частица "не" пишется раздельно с причастиями, у которых есть зависимое слово. В данном случае зависимое слово - это "ничем".

Comment: Там не так всё просто. Есть ряд ситуаций, когда "не" с причастием пишется слитно при наличии зависимого слова. Это ж русский язык, не бывает правил без списка исключений :) http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80

Comment: Здесь дело не в зависимом слове, а в двойном отрицании.